# Yii2 - api rest authentication

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2, webservice-client

I am trying to implement authentication in rest API with `Https Bearer Auth`
I don't have a table of registered users but a table with other apps that have "access_token" permission to access my API.

Is this correct and safe? Will "access_token" be the same forever? and put it directly in the code?

**controller.php**

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'authMethods' => [
                HttpBearerAuth::className(),

        ]];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```

**application components**

```
'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\ApiAccess',
            'enableSession' => false,
            'loginUrl' => null,
        ],
    ],
```

**common/models/ApiAccess** (instead common/models/User)

```
....
 public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }
```

and in this table i have fields: `id`, `app_name`, `access_token`.

**client side**

in client side i use `yiisoft/yii2-httpclient` and i have this code.

```
$client = new Client();
        $response = $client->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->setUrl('http://etc/etc')
            ->addHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer 56265883-****-****-****-************'])
            ->send();
        if ($response->isOk) {
            code.....
        }
```

Comment: i think this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720399/yii2-rest-api-bearer-authentication

Comment: you can bind the api-key and the domain names that are going to consume your api in case your api-key isnt going to change because if somehow anyone steals your clients API key you still have restriction applied with CORS to allow only those domains that are trust worthy

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco basically this is the same as my code.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam this was very useful thanks!